# Type function () view external returns (int256) is not implicitly convertible to expected type int256

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, blockchain

I have two contracts. When accessing an int(team1Score) and trying to subtracting it from another int(team2Score) I got the following error!

this is game contract

```
enum Teams { Team1, Team2 }
int public team1Score;
int public team2Score;

function addScore(Teams teamNumber) external {
    // TODO: add score to the specified team
    if(teamNumber == Teams.Team1)
        team1Score += 1;
    else team2Score += 1;
}
```

and this is bet contract (I imported the game contract here)

```
Game public game;
constructor(address _GameAddress){
    game = Game(_GameAddress);
}

function getScoreDifference(Game.Teams team) public view returns(int256){
    if(team == Game.Teams.Team1)
        return game.team1Score - game.team2Score; // here I got the eror
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When reading public variables from another contract, you need to use the getter functions:

```
return game.team1Score() - game.team2Score();
```

Comment: Oh thanks. So all the state variables should call by the default compiler get function?

Comment: Using the default getters is not mandatory, but more convenient. Or you could implement your own getters, regardless whether its public or private:

function() getTeam1Score() { return team1Score; }